# 2D графика в linux

Tags: графика, библиотеки, c++, linux

посоветуйте 2D библиотеку вывода графики для linux. хотелось бы что нибудь наподобие как библиотека под ДОС - graphics.h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуй [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org), с его помощью много чего написано.

Сам писал на нем небольшой редактор графов.

Answer (score 3):

нашел сам. библиотека xlib

Comment: Интересно, почему минуснули автора?

Считаете, что он не сможет освоить иксы?

Comment: Да, мне тоже интересно, почему минус.

Answer (score 3):

Еще можно попробовать Qt.

Answer (score 3):

Можете попробовать [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Правда там немного большее чем просто библиотека для работы с 2D графикой.